# Two and one straight lines for the same kind of equation in DESMOS.

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question

It is known that many professional mathematicians (including great ones among them) cannot solve math problems from the Olympics, which some adolescents with precarious knowledge can solve.

The question proposed here is, apparently, a problem for high school students, which,however, two solvent people in mathematics whom I have consulted have not been able to solve?. The question should be simple in principle.

Why, for the straight line $y-a=(x-b)\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)$ , DESMOS graphs with two lines in the black and blue cases but with a single line in the red case (see attached figure).

[image]

Comment: same behavior for $(y-2)/(x-3) = 5$   compared with  $(y-2)/(x-3.1) = 5$   so a glitch in the software;

Comment: I can't reproduce your graphing anomaly in DESMOS. I always get one slanted straight line.

Comment: @YNK  I suspect the degree of magnification also contributes to the error. I replaced $3.1$   by $31/10$  extra line, no extra line with $31/11.$  Extra line with $31/110,$  $31/100,$   $31/101, $   also $31/100$

Comment: A possible distinguishing property between red, black and blue: $3$ can be represented precisely in binary, but $1.8$ and $2.4$ can not.

Comment: I sent an email to  support@desmos.com    which is what they want for bug reports from end users.

Answer (score 1):

The correct graph for $\dfrac{y - 5.43}{x- 2.4} = \tan\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{7}\right)$
is a diagonal line with negative slope and a "hole" at $x = 2.4$ since the left-hand side of the equation is undefined there due to a division by zero.

You can easily prove this by noting the division by zero that prevents graphing a point at $x = 2.4$, then plotting the rest of the graph (where $x\neq 2.4$) by multiplying both sides of the equation by $x - 2.4$. Then you get a simple point-slope form of the equation of a line.

Desmos, however, does not always handle undefined values of functions well.
It never shows the location of the "hole" in a graph like this unless you actively probe the function at that exact spot (*),
and in some cases (as demonstrated here) it mistakenly shows a vertical line where the division by zero occurs.

In short, the extra line is nothing more than a software error.

---

To probe for an undefined value of a function like this, you can click with a mouse on the exact spot on the graph where the "hole" is. The "hole" will appear as a small unfilled circle as shown in some textbooks.
Alternatively, you can click on some other point on the graph, which will cause a dot to appear and the coordinates of that point to be displayed,
and you can drag the dot to the point where the "hole" is; if you stop dragging at the moment you reach the "hole", it will appear as a small unfilled circle.

Comment: Desmos has a page for bug reports,   where   one sees "   Hi there! Could you please email support@desmos.com with this concern? Thank you! "   for such individual mathematics errors..

Comment: Actually desmos does show "holes" e.g. in rational functions or $sin(x)/x$, but only if you force it to, by moving a point along the curve with your mouse.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks, I think I have seen this before but had forgotten. I have modified the answer to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

reply, makes sense:

> May 31, 2023, 11:24 AM EDT
>
> Hi William,   This is in fact a known limitation of the system, but
> thanks for taking the time to send us your report! Essentially what's
> happening is this:
>
> When we encounter an implicit equation that's "simple" enough, we
> solve for one of the variables and plot it as a function of the other
> (because plotting explicitly is often much faster than using our
> implicit plotter). When using this technique, we have to try to
> account for the case where there is a second, vertical line solution
> (for instance, in xy=0, if we only solve for one variable or the
> other, we will fail to plot one of the branches). We do this by trying
> to detect whether one of the branches is identically equal to 0. But
> Desmos sometimes have a hard time distinguishing between a coefficient
> being identically 0 and just passing through 0, which can sometimes
> lead us to plotting spurious vertical lines like this.   It's one
> symptom of the compromises we make as a numerical system. I.e., we can
> only plot things by sampling values, and not by trying to prove
> algebraic facts about function behavior.   Hope that helps understand
> what's going on at least. Thanks again for sending us your question!
> Best, Chris @ Desmos

Answer (score 0):

I sent a brief question with screenshots to desmos. The person who replied does not understand that there is a genuine mathematics error involved. If there is a longer exchange, I will try to explain the difference between Piquito's implicit formulation and the more ordinary  and explicit $y= mx + b.$  Note that, if you just type in $2x + 7$  with no letter $y$ and no equals sign, it correctly displays a function.

> Yannabah (Desmos)
>
> May 29, 2023, 5:39 PM EDT
>
> Hi William -   Thanks for reaching out about this issue (and for
> including the links and screen shots).  I believe it is what you and
> others are sharing - it's a result of the floating point arithmetic
> the calculator uses and rounding, but I'm reaching out to our
> engineers for a more in depth answer.  I'll let you know what I hear
> back! all the best, Yannabah & Team Desmos

Comment: Allow me to collectively thank you for your management before Desmos, on behalf of those whom I do not know.